# How do I use foreign keys in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class ParentDeck(models.Model):
    deck_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.deck_name
    
    
class Flashcard(models.Model):
    cardID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    due_date = models.DateField()
    parent_deck = models.ForeignKey(ParentDeck, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This has been killing me for a while now. Any help would be massively appreciated! I'm still a beginner :)

I tried looking up solutions and used ChatGPT [I've learnt that ChatGPT isn't great for these tasks], yet nothing seems to be working.

Comment: What do you mean by "how do i use foreign keys?"

Comment: Exactly *what* do you try to do?

Answer (score 3):

Ok so `ForeignKey` is a [One-to-Many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships) relationship.

The way you have set it up means: 
Every single `Flashcard` is linked to a specific `ParentDeck`. 
Every `ParentDeck` is linked to multiple, or a set of `Flashcard`s.

You can access the linked part like this:

```py
from app.models import Flashcard
f = Flashcard.objects.all().first()
print(f.parentdeck.deck_name)
```

The following is the other way round and called reverse lookup.

```py
from app.models import ParentDeck
d = ParentDeck.objects.all().first()
linked_flashcards = d.flashcard_set.all()
print(linked_flashcards.first().question)
```

The syntax with underscore-"set" or `<object>_set` is the default implementation for reverse django lookups.

Other options for relationships would be:

- one-to-one relationship
- many-to-many relationship

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I still don't entirely get what you mean...Could you perhaps expand on it? I don't mean to be too forward, but if it makes it more convenient for you to communicate on a different medium, I would be more than happy to do so :)

Comment: A `ForeignKey` is one way to express a relationship of objects (models) within Django. This relationship defines the structure of the database and how the tables are linked. What I described is how you can access related objects. To get further help, maybe you can specify the exact roadblock that you are facing? If not I would just copy and paste the documentation that I already linked.